# jstree hide attribute from the tree

Tags: jstree

when i submit following code on this page http://uimonster.com/uimexamples/example_01/example_01a.html i get treeview from this view i want to hide attribute nodes.. how can i hide these extra nodes.

```
<bussinessline>  
<PRODUCTGROUPS>
<Name ID="123"> ABC</Name>
<Name ID="456"> XYZ</Name>
<Name ID="789">PQR</Name>
</PRODUCTGROUPS>
</bussinessline>
```

Comment: Is your code that creates jsTree?

Comment: The example doesn't work. I didn't quite understand the question. Could you supply a code sample?

Answer (score 0):

If you can set the "state" of the nodes containing the nodes you don't want to see to "closed", that will hide them until you open the parent node. You would do this in your data. See [jsTree, JSON and MVC3 objects. How to structure data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558882/jstree-json-and-mvc3-objects-how-to-structure-data) for help.