# jsTree, JSON and MVC3 objects. How to structure data

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, jstree

I have been playing with JsTree a little and MVC3. I can successfully call MVC3 methods and get back JSON to load a basic JsTree so i can do the very basics. What i don't understand is the more complicated data structure to use mostly to do wait extra data i need on nodes and also getting the tree to act on some of that data.

My data is
NodeText (string) - text to display

ItemStatus (enum) - Used to set colors etc on tree

ItemType (enum) - controls what can be dragged and dropped and onto what

RelatedIDs (List ID is a struct described below) - used when an item is dropped

PrimaryItemID (ID and is a struct) - used for right click menu and DB item identification and applying info for RelatedIDs from dropped item.

SecondaryItemID (ID and is a struct) - used for right click menu and DB item identification and applying info for RelatedIDs from dropped item.

```
ID struct is
ID (long) 
IDType (enum)
```

From my reading i understand the JSON data layout may have changed as well as there been attribute data and meta data but i am not very clear on what should go where and what MVC3 model object i should create to serialize this data into JSON the tree can understand. I really want to get the base data structure right the first time so i don't have to rewrite a heap of code.

If i have left any required info out let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the data model I have been using for JSTree. You will have to put it in json form.

```
node.data.attr.href          <a> tag within <li> href
              .other-a-attr  any other attribute you want on the <a>
         .title              visible title of node  
         .icon               optional image_file for icon
    .state                   controls icon, "open", "closed" or "" = default
    .arrt.id                 node id on the <li>
         .nType              type_attr for UI and types plug ins - MUST SET using type_attr in Types plugin default is ref
         .title              node title (not visible)
         .other-li-attr      any other attritubes you want on the <li>
```

I have to agree JSTree has a very steep learning curve and getting this out of the documentation is not at all easy for us newbees.

I am still not sure what node.arrt.title is for. It is not the title you see in the tree. node.data.title is the one that shows in the tree.

There may be others that I have not figured out yet. Let me know if you figure them out.

Comment: Thanks! That is the best description of all tags and values i have seen and i spent a lot of time working most of those out last night myself. Wish i had seen this post.  Also of note is that on events .arrt.other-li-attr are very easy to access.  I have not worked out how to acee the same thing under data yet.

Comment: @seer I think a lot of us have spent those hours pulling our hair out. JSTree is a great resource but getting to the details of how to use it takes a lot of time.

Comment: Little off topic but have you played with DND at all? Trying to have 2 trees where one tree is items and other tree is commands.  Drop an command on an item to run that command against that item.  command would not get moved or copied.  I tried the node move stuff talked about between tries but found it always copies or moves the node so am about to try DND. Do you know if that would work how i want.  Just want to trigger a javascript function. I think it should but if you know it could save me hours of testing :)

Comment: @seer I have never used two trees together that way. It is an interesting concept what you are doing with commands and item. I would post a new question about it so other people will see it. Hope you can get it working. I know I would like to see it when you get there.

Comment: for those interested in what i just asked in my comment above this post covers it.  http://groups.google.com/group/jstree/browse_thread/thread/a9bdf05a72c8c1f6?pli=1

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter what language you use for the backend. In your response the JSON has to look in a certain way. The basic jsTree acceptable JSON format is:

```
[
   {
      "data" : {
         "icon" : "/path/to/icon.png",
         "title" : "name of the node"
      },
      "attr" : {
         "rel" : "type defined by types",
         "title" : "node title",
         "id" : "Node id"
      },
      "state" : "closed"
   }
]
```

Obviously., this is just an example you can play around with. Naturally, you can put `null` in icon, or completely drop it. The `rel` has to be defined by the `types` plugin, but is also optional, so is the title.

Comment: Naturally this is an array and you may add as many objects to it as you need.

Comment: so how do you know what to put in data vs attr?  That is more i am having issues with working out where i need to put things for things like DND, types, context menus etc to work and pass me the info i need or does it jsut return the whole node.

Comment: the data is fixed, the title is the node's title. In the attr you can put whatever you want, the common options that people widely use are the `rel`/`id`/`title` but you can add as you need.
You should read in the documentation about each plug in how to make it work. Usually you get a data object (`data.rslt.o`) you can manipulate and send what you want back to the server.

Comment: "the data is fixed" perfect where did you find that? As far as i could find it sounded like both data and attr could be added to and that data was the recommended one if it did not need to be a pysical attr but i was not sure.  Also when you say attr do you mean the one directly on the node or the attr under data as there is two. That is what confuses me there seems to be multiple places for data but no explination of what is for what and is it the node or data or attr that gets returned to functions for DND, context menus etc.

Comment: Well, read the documentation and check the jsTree source code. Basically there are two JSON formats (which are pretty similar) that the jsTree expects for each node. In any case, basically everything is returned. You get a node object and you can access anything. It might be more complicated to access the `data` part of the object (using plain javascript for example, check firebug) whereas using attr is pretty straight forward, i.e in the DND or context menu plugins: `data.rslt.o.attr("id")`

Comment: ok.  yea already gone through the doco on the site but found it laking in explaining the diff between data, data.attr and attr and different examples use different ones so i ended up confused.  i will move everything to the root attr collect on the node then.  Thanks